Competing formula for combined azimuth and pitch angle
To calculate the total angle from combined horizontal and vertical angles, I have one source telling me
$$\text{Total Angle} = \sqrt{\text{h_angle}^2 + \text{v_angle}^2}$$
But other sources say (for example here that the calculation is
$$\text{Total Angle} = \arccos(\cos(\text{h_angle})\cos(\text{v_angle}))$$
They are close especially for horizontal/vertical angles close to 0.
Which formula is correct?

If the situation is as shown in the link you provided, then the formula given there
$$total\_angle = \arccos (\cos(v\_angle)\cos(h\_angle))$$
is correct.
The formula form the first source is an approximation that works well for small angles, because then
$$\cos (x) \approx 1-\frac{x^2}2$$
is a good approximation of the cosine, the next term with order $x^4$ often being negligible.
Using this, we get
$$\cos(h\_angle) \cos (v\_angle) \approx  (1-\frac{h\_angle^2}2)(1-\frac{v\_angle^2}2) = 1-\frac{h\_angle^2}2 - \frac{v\_angle^2}2 + \frac{h\_angle^2v\_angle^2}4 \approx 1-\frac{h\_angle^2}2 - \frac{v\_angle^2}2,$$
by again omiting the term of order $4$.
Applying the arccos to both side of the approximation, and again remembering the initial approximation for $\cos(x)$, this leads to
$$ total\_angle^2 \approx v\_angle^2 + h\_angle^2,$$
leading to the approximation of the first source.

When you have two formulas that don't agree, try them with non-trivial data where you know the correct answer.
A pitch angle of $\frac\pi2$ radians ($90$ degrees) gives you a direction that is "straight up" regardless of the azimuth.
That is, if you take an azimuth of $\frac\pi2$ and pitch of $\frac\pi2$,
you end up in a direction that makes the same total angle with the direction "azimuth $0$, pitch $0$" that you get when you take an azimuth of $0$ and pitch of $\frac\pi2$.
So plug $\text{h_angle} = 0$, $\text{v_angle} = \frac\pi2$ into each of your equations.
Then try $\text{h_angle} = \frac\pi2$, $\text{v_angle} = \frac\pi2$.
A correct equation will give the same answer for both sets of input.
If you get a different answer for $\text{h_angle} = \frac\pi2$, $\text{v_angle} = \frac\pi2$
than for $\text{h_angle} = 0$, $\text{v_angle} = \frac\pi2$, you have an incorrect equation.
This exercise won't prove that you have a correct formula, but it will show you when a formula is incorrect.
If you want to know why one source said that the formula
$\text{Total Angle} = \sqrt{\text{h_angle}^2 + \text{v_angle}^2}$ was useful, we would need to see exactly what that source said about the formula, including any assumptions that were made about h_angle and v_angle.
I suspect that if we were to see this source, we would find that it assumes the angles are small (as pointed out in another answer)
and that it assumes it is easier to compute two squares and a square root than to compute two cosines and an arc cosine.
